# How do I render icon font glyphs on a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using a font from http://icomoon.io/ on a project and need to draw this to a canvas element with `fillText`.

```
var charCode = 0xe00e;
context.font = "20px icomoon";
context.fillText(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
```

The font is being included in CSS (and is also installed locally) but instead of the picture of a house I want to see, it renders a '2'.

What can I do to debug this problem?

To be a bit clearer: I'm trying to render specific glyphs by character code rather than straightforward strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/wsU3m/)**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KulminoituvaRegular';
    src: url('http://www.miketaylr.com/f/kulminoituva.ttf');
}
```

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '36px KulminoituvaRegular';
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillText  ('Kulminoituva Regular', 10, 10);
```

Comment: That's a useful demo of how to use @font-face with canvas but my real issue is that I can't get glyphs to render by unicode character (or even be sure which font the canvas element thinks it's using!)

Comment: @MichaelForrest: I see. And you're absolutely certain you have the correct charcodes? Could you post a screenshot of what the Canvas' showing, and where are you getting the charcodes from? (**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsU3m/1/)** Appears to be working properly, so I suspect the `CharCode` is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm, when I change your fiddle to use (my locally installed) icomoon font it works...

Comment: But it doesn't work in my app. I need to figure out how to see what font the canvas element thinks it can use...

Comment: Hm, Good luck hunting down the problem!
Meanwhile, could you consider accepting my answer, as it might be as close as we can get? :3

Comment: Ok it looks like I had a weirdly corrupted font that was aliased as icomoon. I'll accept your answer to help others with less weird problems than I had ;)

Answer (score 1):

One fix is to just use the SVG font that ico moon provides. That's the line that looks like this:

```
url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg')
```

I believe the canvas needs that SVG data to render the icon, if you are using one of the other various font formats (eot, woff, ttf) the canvas doesn't know how to interpret the unicode conversion.

The good news is that svg is supported in all the same browsers as the html canvas.

Update: To clarify, your font embed should have the SVG line after all the other src lines like so:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting \u before the desired character code for e.g. if character code is '0xe00e', use '\u0xe00e'

```
 context.font = '20px icomoon';
 context.fillText('\u0xe00e', 20, 20);
```